# How to use Graphics.DrawProcedural to render a quad over a scene?

Tags: unity, shaders, graphics-programming

I want to learn this so I could do some screen space particles in Unity. This is meant as a sort of "hello world" shader.

my current script is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ParticleFX : MonoBehaviour
{

public int particlecount = 4;
private Material material;

void Start()
{
        material = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/CustomParticle"));
}


void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{

    material.SetPass(0);
    Graphics.DrawProcedural(MeshTopology.Quads, particlecount, 1);

}

void OnDestroy()
{

}
}
```

And my shader looks like this:

```
Shader "Hidden/CustomParticle"
{
SubShader
{
    Pass
{
    CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#include "UnityCG.cginc"
#pragma target 3.5

    struct v2f {
    fixed4 color : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
};

v2f vert(
    uint vid : SV_VertexID // vertex ID, needs to be uint
)
{
    v2f o;
    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(float3(vid>>1,vid&1,1));
    o.color = float4(1,0,0,1);
    return o;
}

fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    return i.color;
}
    ENDCG
  }
 }
}
```

I expect to see a red quad cover my scene, but I don't. The core part is learning to use Graphics.DrawProcedural().

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnRenderImage.html) of this feature? There it says you need to attach the script to a camera and then do a blit or render a full-screen quad.

Comment: it is attached to  the camera I have